# How do I remove the front axle from a sealed bearing hub?

Tags: wheels

I'm trying to remove the axle from my front wheel to fit it into a box.  But the axle doesn't want to come out.  I've been able to take all the bits off of one side, but I can't remove the ones from the other side, the axle is just spinning while I try and unscrew them.

I expected after I had got one side free that I could just pull it out, but it is not coming out.

I'm not really sure what to do next, every video and explanation I can find on this says that it should just come out.

[image: Everything going ok]

[image: Can't remove these]

Comment: Some early sealed bearings had an axle with no sort of inner cone, and the axles would slide out, leaving the bearings in place.  But apparently that's not what you have.

Answer (score 6):

The wheel has sealed bearing that are pressed into the hub. Your axle is likely being held in by the bearings. The axle has flanges on the inside that the bearing is resting against. You can try tapping on the end of the axle with a soft faced hammer or even a block of wood. This should dislodge the bearing from the hub. This will also damage the bearing. I would look for a larger box and avoid the hassle of buying new bearings and the tools needed to install them.

Answer (score 4):

That's an interesting wheel - I'm guessing its an 80s racing front wheel, - *or its designed to look like one* - because of the low spoke count and the large flange hub.

Most wheels have cup and cones to hold ball bearings.  Yours has sealed cartridge bearings instead, so its like roller blades or skateboards.

I'd lay the wheel on its side, support the nut side with some kind of tube that will press on the hub but not the cartridge, and tap the axle downwards into your support tube.

It may help to apply some easing oil around the cartridge the night before and let it soak.

You will need to buy probably two new replacement cartridges of the same inner/outer diameter and width.  The higher the ABEC rating, the more precise the bearings.  Rollerblades can be found using ABEC 5/7/9 in the good ones, or ABEC 1 for cheaper ones.

Shop around for bearings - a bearing seller will probably be better than a sports shop.

Comment: Good although ABEC really has no bearing on bearing quality: http://skateboard.about.com/od/skateboardinglifestyle/a/Bearing_Truth.htm

Comment: @RoboKaren "The higher the ABEC rating, the more precise the bearings"  I should have said tolerance instead.   Sadly there's a definite correlation in price.

Comment: It's not an old hub, it's a cheap Quando as fitted to many cheap Fixies.