# How do I remove a threaded rear axle with cartridge bearings?

Tags: bearings, axle

I'm trying to remove the axle in the picture. I think the bearings say "Enduro 6000LLB" on the sides. How can I remove the axle and the bearings?

I checked out [this post](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/36702/how-do-i-remove-the-front-axle-from-a-sealed-bearing-hub), which suggested I tap the axle to get the axle and one of the bearings out. I tried bracing the hub against a piece of pipe and rapping with a rubber mallet, then with a piece of 2x4 wood, with light to moderate force each time, but the bearing didn't budge.

I could try hitting harder, but before applying more force I want to make sure I'm not doing the wrong thing.

Also, I don't know for certain if the axle has flanges on the inside, but I can only assume it does.[image]

Answer (score 6):

Solved. I simply was not hammering hard enough. Kudos to my wife who had experience removing bearings from buses for explaining to me that sometimes bearings can be stubborn and that extra force didn't matter since I was going to replace the bearing anyway.

Once I had it apart, I confirmed it was a flanged axle as described in [the post I linked to in my original question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/36702/how-do-i-remove-the-front-axle-from-a-sealed-bearing-hub).

Answer (score 0):

The axle is clearly threaded so you will need to turn something.

Start by wiping down the area to remove most of the dirt.  That should reveal two flat areas on opposite sides of the locknut and the inner nut.

I would use two cone spanners of the correct size to loosen the locknut off the inner nut.  Note there appears to be a spacer between them too - that may be threaded, but probably not.

Once one side's retaining nuts are off the axle should push out the other side of the hub.

Then to remove the bearings you need to feed in a bearing removal tool and tap that to push the bearings out from the inside.  Or use a piece of brass as a soft-punch and slowly work the bearing out.  Brass is less likely to damage the housing.
Removing a cartridge bearing with force will generally damage it, so don't expect to reinstall the bearing again.  You will need new bearings.

Comment: Right, it's not shown in the pic but all the nuts/washers were removed from the other side. So the nuts shown in the picture were being hammered away from the wheel, not toward it. Fortunately I was able to get it apart (see my answer below).